# How do I delete a folder

Tags: directory, root, delete

I have created a folder in my file system called "opt". It contains two other folders. How do I delete it with signing in as a root user? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open terminal - Type this command and hit enter key

```
sudo gksu nautilus
```

Now, enter your password, After you can go to "opt" directory and delete it

Comment: Awesome awesome...... i just killed the file. You deserve a cup of coffee. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`rmdir` will not work here as it will  only remove empty directories

use `rm` with some additional flags

`rm -r` will recurse and delete everything in the folder

`rm -f` will force the removal of a directory. `rm` is not for removing directories

put these together and your command should be `rm -rf /path/to/opt`

Depending on the permissions of the folder you might need to use `sudo rm -rf /path/to/opt`

Check out `man rm` to get some extra info.

Comment: As on the other answer: I would suggest that it'd be (slightly) safer to use the full path to this folder, i.e. `rm -rf /path/to/opt`. You really don't want to risk removing `/opt`.

Comment: Oh yeah, Good call.

Comment: I've used this and it wouldn't work. I have had to do it from inside the "opt" folder too. This folder "java" and "spotify" inside them. The java one has "64" in it while 64 has "jre1.7.0_25" in it. Thanks

Comment: Im curious why this didn't work. What error did you get?

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't create it as root, `rm -r opt` should work. Otherwise, try `sudo rm -r opt`.

Comment: I would suggest that it'd be (slightly) safer to use the full path to this folder, i.e. `rm -r /path/to/opt`. You really don't want to risk removing `/opt`.